# Setup Updated Apache Http Components for android

Tags: android, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use a code with apache HttpClient 4.5  thats works fine in a separated java aplication,  when I bring to android project I have this error

```
java.lang.nosuchfielderror org.apache.http.conn.ssl.allowallhostnameverifier
```

code:

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(),new HostnameVerifier(){
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I import the same libs , i googleit and says a duplicate reference or a jar  missed but nothing
I download the jar from here https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi 
If the problems is in the jars that are no compatible with android I like to find the correct jars without using gradle  maven or something like this because the mayor time im offline and when online only can navigate the web
Thanks

Comment: If your android app uses API23, these library becomes unusable, you can read the comments of @Marek in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957941/android-project-uses-httpclient-4-5/31958072?noredirect=1#comment52242740_31958072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import httpclient, because it would create conflict with existing library.

However you may want to use this, this is the official way suggested by apache

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

> Background
>
> Google Android 1.0 was released with a pre-BETA snapshot of Apache
>   HttpClient. To coincide with the first Android release Apache
>   HttpClient 4.0 APIs had to be frozen prematurely, while many of
>   interfaces and internal structures were still not fully worked out. As
>   Apache HttpClient 4.0 was maturing the project was expecting Google to
>   incorporate the latest code improvements into their code tree.
>   Unfortunately it did not happen. Version of Apache HttpClient shipped
>   with Android has effectively become a fork. Eventually Google decided
>   to discontinue further development of their fork while refusing to
>   upgrade to the stock version of Apache HttpClient citing compatibility
>   concerns as a reason for such decision. As a result those Android
>   developers who would like to continue using Apache HttpClient APIs on
>   Android cannot take advantage of newer features, performance
>   improvements and bug fixes.
>
> Apache HttpClient 4.3 port for Android is intended to remedy the
>   situation by providing official releases compatible with Google
>   Android.

Alternatively, you can also consider okhttp, however, seems okhttp is now included on Android M, I have not tested if it would have similar conflict.
okhttp, has two type of wrapper, one is similar to urlConnection, one is similar to httpclient, you should be able to migrate in a very short time.

https://github.com/square/okhttp

Comment: I will switch OKhttp after try Apache HttpClient 4.3 port for Android i can setup nothing