# which apache http component to add to gradle for multipart-form

Tags: android, apache, http, android-gradle-plugin, multipartform-data

My question is actually a follow up to [Android upload video to remote server using HTTP multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data?lq=1)

I need to know which dependencies to add to gradle for the code to work. I tried as below but it does not work

```
//apache http client
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have answered at the following question:

[Android project uses HttpClient 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957941/android-project-uses-httpclient-4-5/)

You can use `HttpClient for Android 4.3.5` instead.

However, because of the deprecation of Apache's librabry from API22, suggest that you use HttpUrlConnection, OkHttp... instead.

You should read more [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still haven't been able to confirm your answer as I am still looking to see how I might use HttpUrlConnection to upload video using multipart. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data?lq=1 but without using Apache. As soon as I get the code to work, I will confirm.

Comment: Another options are OkHttp, Retrofit, I think in SO many sample codes available

Comment: You should also read [here](http://mysecondmemory.weebly.com/android/multipartform-data-requests-in-android-httpurlconnection-vs-okhttp). Hope this helps!