# Android- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease' in android 1.5.1

Tags: android

The problem is that when I'm debugging in android studio 1.5 is that it fails so many times and this is the message. Then on the jdk part what should I use? I'm using android-studio 1.5.1

**message build gradle**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidmadsLibraryQrgenearatorQRGenearator103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2520Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthApiPhone1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAwareness1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCastFramework1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesClearcut1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGass1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesInstantapps1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlaces1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerV4Impl1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVisionCommon1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAppindexing1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDynamicLinks1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon1104Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePlDroidsonroidsGifAndroidGifDrawable128Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.withFirstParameter(Prototype.java:399)
    at com.android.dx.rop.type.Prototype.intern(Prototype.java:208)
    at com.android.dx.cf.iface.StdMethod.<init>(StdMethod.java:46)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MethodListParser.set(MethodListParser.java:81)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MemberListParser.parse(MemberListParser.java:217)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MemberListParser.parseIfNecessary(MemberListParser.java:108)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.MethodListParser.getList(MethodListParser.java:54)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:565)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:420)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:402)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:253)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:774)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1600(Main.java:86)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1745)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:757)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:725)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:86)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1698)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:679)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:571)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:368)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:289)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:247)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:94)


**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 3**
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.home.bloodbank"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    android {
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'

    compile 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.3'
}


android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Google JAR file causing GC overhead limit exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013638/android-studio-google-jar-file-causing-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-error)

Comment: Just clean your project and rebuild as said in this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception/32826010#32826010)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android project uses HttpClient 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957941/android-project-uses-httpclient-4-5)

Comment: aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false   
     aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false                                                       
      add these line build.gradle (insde android{})

Comment: Error:(25, 0) No signature of method: java.lang.Boolean.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [false]
Possible solutions: and(java.lang.Boolean), wait(), any(), wait(long), xor(java.lang.Boolean), or(java.lang.Boolean)
<a href="openFile:E:\BloodBank\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle

```
repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
}
```

ANOTHER SOLUTION: Utilize specific dependencies—don't just import an entire section of dependencies!

For example, if you need the Play Services dependency for location, only import it for location.

DO:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

DON'T:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'
```

---

**UPDATE:**

REASON 1 : Duplicate of class file name

SOLUTION :

when your refactoring of some of your class files to a library project. and that time you write name of class file So, double check that you do not have any duplicate names

REASON 2 : When you have lot of cache Memory

SOLUTION :

Sometime if you have lot of cache memory then this error occure so solve it. go to File/Invalidate caches / Restart then select Invalidate and Restart it will clean your cache memory.

REASON 3 : When there is internal bug or used beta Version to Switch back to stable version.

SOLUTION :

Solution is just simple go to Build menu and click Clean Project and after cleaning click Rebuild Project.

REASON 4 : When you memory of the system Configuration is low.

SOLUTION :

open Task Manager and stop the other application which are not most used at that time so it will free the space and solve OutOfMemory.

REASON 5 : The problem is your method count has exceed from 65K.

SOLUTION :

open your Project build.gradle file add

```
 defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

and in dependencies add below line.

```
dependencies 
    {

   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    }
```

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

and

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

at the same time.

Comment: they're the same, just different versions. https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents

Comment: ive deleted compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5' then heres another error ;                                                                                
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1